# How to send wishlist item quotation in PDF format via email to customer- Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, quote, pdf, wishlist

I want to send the wishlist quotation in PDF format to the currently logged in customer.

Magento has the option to share a wishlist, but it only lets you share with another recipient where as I would like the user to be able to click and have the quotation emailed to themselves in a PDF format.

This is complete new for me so please help me. thanks in advance